# Scaling and minimum quorum size

Tags: hazelcast

If Kubernetes auto-scales of a Hazelcast IMDG cluster, how can I update the minimum-cluster-size to match the new quorum requirements?

E.g. I have a 3-instance cluster with minimum cluster size set to 2. The cache is getting full, so Kubernetes decides to spin another two instances. How can I update the minimum cluster size to 3 now? Or the other way round, Kubernetes now shuts down 2 instances, how can I update the minimum cluster size back to 2?

I am using Hazelcast embedded with Spring Boot if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot dynamically change `minimum-cluster-size` in Hazelcast, so it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a dynamically changing quorum size by implementing your own custom `QuorumFunction` and configuring your quorum to use that. For example:

```
public class DynamicQuorumSize implements QuorumFunction {
    private volatile int minimumClusterSize;

    @Override
    public boolean apply(Collection<Member> members) {
        // don't lookup minimumClusterSize here from external services, DBs
        // or other slow sources
        return members.size() >= minimumClusterSize;
    }

    // allow updating minimum cluster size
    public void setQuorumSize(int minimumClusterSize) {
        this.minimumClusterSize = minimumClusterSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I get reduced collection of members, how do I know if that's due to clean shutdown or due to network partition? I don't want to reduce the minimum cluster size if I get a network partition.